# Как сохранить pendingIntent в sPref, или как удалить определенный будильник

Tags: java, android

У меня будильники. Я создаю будильник вот так

```
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(CreateAlarmClock.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Таких будильников я делаю до 6-ти штук. Как мне Удалить один из них по запросу юзера? Для сохранения я использую SharedPreferences, сохраняю я в Set  объекты Alarm с геттерами\сеттерами времени и описания.

Как я понял, что-бы удалить один из будильников, нужно вызвать метод cancel

```
AlarmManager.cancel(pIntent);
```

Но как мне сохранить определенный pIntent будильника, что бы потом его удалить?

**т.е.** юзер нажимает кнопку, начинает работать метод который достает из sPref информацию по pIntent и удаляет этот будильник.

```
public class Alarm {
//этот класс я сохраняю, что-бы потом заполнить textView
private Calendar calendar;
private String   time;
```

Comment: Ну вы же можете достать из Preferences конкретный будильник, так в чем проблема с его оттуда удалением?

Comment: Как? sPref же не может сохранить alarmManager?

Comment: Тогда вопрос. А что вы там сохраняете?

Comment: sPref может сохранить только простые типы и Set<String>. В моем случае он сохраняет время(String), что-бы после после перезагрузки активити заполнить TextView. А мне нужно удалить сигнализацию AM, для этого нужно знать конкретный PendingIntent, как мне его сохранить и инициализировать при необходимости?

Comment: Ну вот смотрите, у вас в префах лежит время(кстати не только String можно хранить, ну да ладно). При запуске вы создаете интенты по этим значения. Ну так складывайте эти интенты в `HashMap<String, Intent>`, а если надо удалить, то удаляетй строку из префов и интент с помощью `AlarmManager.cancel(intentsHashMap.get(ваша_строка))`

Comment: Если я правильно понял, необходимо выборочно удалить определённый Alarm. Для этого `PendigIntent` необходимо присвоить индентификатор  - второй параметр в `getBroadcast()` ,  и сохранить в `Preferences`. Ну а для удаления необходимо снова создать `PendingIntent` c этим же идентификатором и затем уже `AlarmManager.cancel(pIntent);`